# Should this (gfx-rs) glutin window really take a full second to load?

Tags: rust, glfw

I'm trying to start working with [gfx-rs](https://github.com/gfx-rs/gfx) and have simply copied the source code from [the triangle example](https://github.com/gfx-rs/gfx/tree/9e9a3301342595c06ce6b5e4df67ae661dcadb49/examples/triangle) just to make sure things run.  I noticed that the window was taking a noticeable amount of time to fully load. It appears to *open* relatively quickly but I can see a completely blank (white) window for close to a second. I threw some timing checks in to see what part of the code was bogging things down.

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "graphics"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
gfx = "0.14"
gfx_macros = "0.2"
glutin = "0.7.1"
gfx_window_glutin = "0.14"
time = "*"
fps_counter = "*"
```

main.rs

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate gfx;
extern crate gfx_window_glutin;
extern crate glutin;
extern crate time;
extern crate fps_counter;

use time::PreciseTime;
use gfx::traits::FactoryExt;
use gfx::Device;
// use fps_counter::FPSCounter;
use std::io;
// use std::time::Duration;
// use std::thread::sleep;


pub type ColorFormat = gfx::format::Rgba8;
pub type DepthFormat = gfx::format::DepthStencil;

gfx_defines!{
    vertex Vertex {
        pos: [f32; 2] = "a_Pos",
        color: [f32; 3] = "a_Color",
    }

    pipeline pipe {
        vbuf: gfx::VertexBuffer<Vertex> = (),
        out: gfx::RenderTarget<ColorFormat> = "Target0",
    }
}

const TRIANGLE: [Vertex; 3] = [
    Vertex { pos: [ -0.5, -0.5 ], color: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
    Vertex { pos: [  0.5, -0.5 ], color: [0.0, 1.0, 0.0] },
    Vertex { pos: [  0.0,  0.5 ], color: [0.0, 0.0, 1.0] }
];

const CLEAR_COLOR: [f32; 4] = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0];

pub fn main() {
    let mut start = PreciseTime::now();
    let builder = glutin::WindowBuilder::new()
        .with_title("Triangle example".to_string())
        .with_dimensions(1024, 768)
        .with_vsync();
    let mut end = PreciseTime::now();
    println!("window builder: {}", start.to(end).num_milliseconds());
    start = PreciseTime::now();
    let (window, mut device, mut factory, main_color, mut main_depth) =
        gfx_window_glutin::init::<ColorFormat, DepthFormat>(builder);
    end = PreciseTime::now();
    println!("init window: {}", start.to(end).num_milliseconds());

    start = PreciseTime::now();
    let mut encoder: gfx::Encoder<_, _> = factory.create_command_buffer().into();
    let pso = factory.create_pipeline_simple(
        include_bytes!("shader/triangle_150.glslv"),
        include_bytes!("shader/triangle_150.glslf"),
        pipe::new()
    ).unwrap();
    let (vertex_buffer, slice) = factory.create_vertex_buffer_with_slice(&TRIANGLE, ());
    let mut data = pipe::Data {
        vbuf: vertex_buffer,
        out: main_color
    };

    // let mut fps = FPSCounter::new();
    // let mut count = 0;
    end = PreciseTime::now();
    println!("setup: {}", start.to(end).num_milliseconds());

    'main: loop {
        // loop over events
        for event in window.poll_events() {
            match event {
                glutin::Event::KeyboardInput(_, _, Some(glutin::VirtualKeyCode::Escape)) |
                glutin::Event::Closed => break 'main,
                glutin::Event::Resized(_width, _height) => {
                    gfx_window_glutin::update_views(&window, &mut data.out, &mut main_depth);
                },
                _ => {},
            }
        }
        // draw a frame
        encoder.clear(&data.out, CLEAR_COLOR);
        encoder.draw(&slice, &pso, &data);
        encoder.flush(&mut device);
        window.swap_buffers().unwrap();
        device.cleanup();
        // count = fps.tick();
    }

    // println!("fps: {}", count);
    // let mut entered = String::new();
    // io::stdin().read_line(&mut entered)
    //     .expect("Failed to read line");
}
```

The output of the above shows the call to initialize the window is taking almost a second.

> window builder: 0
>
> init window: 933
>
> setup: 3

the line in question:

```
let (window, mut device, mut factory, main_color, mut main_depth) =
    gfx_window_glutin::init::<ColorFormat, DepthFormat>(builder);
```

This happens via cargo run, debug and release, as well as running the executable directly from the build output folder.

Is this to be expected?

**System Information:**

- Windows 10, 64 bit
- i7-4720HQ, 16GB RAM, GTX-960M
- OpenGL 4.4
- Rust 1.19.0

Comment: This feels like it's going to be a system configuration issue. I'd encourage you to add what OS you are using, what video card drivers you are using, what version of OpenGL, maybe even details on the hardware. The other guess I have is that it's actually runtime compilation of the shaders; you could also try removing parts of the program to see if you can identify that as the actual culprit.

Comment: @Shepmaster Added my specs.  I also just upgraded my NVIDIA drivers and it doesn't seem to have helped.  It might have even made things worse (over 2 second on average now) but I can't be certain that was the cause.  EDIT: Running with my integrated graphics card drops it down to 50 milliseconds? Does anyone know why?

Comment: @plast1k Did you explore the possibility of runtime compilation of the shaders? Maybe you can compile them at compile time? You can search some question about precompiled shaders like this: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/153087-Precompiled-GLSL